# MOI about a diagonal

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

If by taking a thin rod, and finding its Moment of Inertia about an axis, say through the mid point of its side, one can observe that stretching the rod uniformly along the axis of rotation will give the shape of a uniform rectangle whose MOI is the same with the thin uniform rod. What happens when you decide to go back to these first principles in knowing the MOI of a rectangle about its diagonal?

[image: Pictorial aid]

Comment: Are you trying to use integration to find the MI about the diagonal or do you want to deduce the result using the known MI about a diameter?

Comment: Finding out a deductive process would help me consider this for other scenarios; I'm yet to study on the integration process, but I'm convinced I should be able to deduce a solution from known results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the red axis be the $s$ axis and draw another axis through the centre parallel to the plane of the lamina and perpendicular to the $s$ axis. Call this the $t$ axis.

By symmetry, $I_s=I_t$.

By Perpendicular Axes, $$I_s+I_t=I_z,$$ where $z$ is the axis perpendicular to the plane of the lamina and through the centre.

You already have the result that $I_z=\frac 23ma^2$ by similar consideration of the MI about a diameter and the Perpendicular Axes Theorem.

Therefore the MI about a diagonal is $$\frac 13ma^2$$

Comment: A similar process doesn't seem to work when I apply it to a rhombus

Comment: You would need to use a trangular lamina as the basic element to calculate the MI of a rhombus or parallelogram

Comment: ah, I see. I'll find that out and work from there, see where I get

Comment: Although I think it's noteworthy that the MI about a perp. plane can be obtained from the basic MI formula of a rectangle, or is this just a coincidence?